# Mobile auto scaling of images

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mobile, responsive-design

I have a basic static S.P.A. that I've gotten styled the way I want when developing on a laptop.  When I test on a mobile viewport and scroll up or down the images/content resize.  I believe that is built into the chrome mobile browser but I'm wondering if there may be a way to disable or to style around this?  A few of the sections of content utilize full background images with text overlaid on top.  When the user scrolls and the image resizes it pushes the content into the next section vs. having a clean ending point.  I know it's possible because I use mobile pages all the time that don't have this issue.  I just don't know how to do it.

```css
    .landingImage {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/Black_gram.jpg');
    background-position: right;
    background-size: cover;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto ;
    }

    .titleContainer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 85vw;
    height: 75vh;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: 2px solid white;
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16vw;
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px black;
    }

    .titleText {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
      }
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <div class="landingImage">
    <div class="titleContainer">
        <h1 class="titleText">SHIFT<br>WORKS<br>BICYCLE<br>OPERATIONS</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MoatazZaitoun I was taught that it meant Single Page Application.  Although in this instance it's really just a static page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue I can see is that the landingImage and titleContainer divs have their heights set relative to the viewport width, e.g.

```
.landingImage {
 ...
 height: 100vh;  
 ...
}
```

This means that if the viewport is say 400px wide, the .landingImage div will be 400px high, and this may not be enough.

One option is to use @media queries in you CSS and refine the height of these divs based on the viewport width. e.g.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .landingImage {
     height: 200vh; 
   }     
}
```

Another possibility is that in your existing CSS you add rule so that the div doesn't shrink below a certain minimum, e.g.

```
.landingImage {
  ...
  min-height: 800px  
  ...
}
```

You can set any number of @media media statements and refine the settings to match the specifics of your page.

Good luck!

Comment: I need to play with it more, but it seems that my vh for heights was messing things up.  Seems obvious but I didn't think about it when I started writing the styles.  Thanks!

Comment: That's great, thanks for letting me know @adam.shaleen